# Timezone issue when searching SQL Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a search model that sends a date range to a stored procedure. The stored procedure returns back results. This works fine where I am in Central Time.

However we have users in India and they could input valid dates of lets say '08/15/2017 23:00' and in the table for them the date is '08/14/2017' so they don't get any data returned.

If they input 08/14/2017 they get the wrong data. Data from 08/13/2017

How can I address the issue of time zone in c# before sending it to the stored procedure?

I have tried this with no luck

```
public DateTime AdjustForTimezone(DateTime date)
{
    TimeZoneInfo timeInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName);
    var newDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date);
    return newDate;
}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getTableData", connection);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);           
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = AdjustForTimezone(dateModel.FromDate);
cmd.Parameters[2].Value = AdjustForTimezone(dateModel.toDate);
```

Comment: DB should have times stored as UTC, C# should convert all times entered to UTC before execution [MS: Converting between time zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones)

Comment: The clients should send DateTime instances to the server either as UTC or with the current offset from UTC. The database should persist the DateTime either as UTC or use DateTimeOffset and persist it with the offset. Personally I prefer storing DateTime/2 as UTC over DateTimeOffset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Client to Server

The clients should send date time instances to the server with a `UTC` value or with the current offset from UTC.

The database should persist the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx)) as [DateTime/2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) (or use [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql)).

#### Server to Client

The server should send the date time information to the client with the UTC value (or offset from UTC). It is the client's responsibility to apply the client's desired offset when the date time is presented (ie. do it in the presentation layer as late as possible).

#### Serialization

If you have to serialize your date times use [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation.

---

By applying the above rules you now have stored your date time values in a way that they are comparable and unambiguous. They can now be filtered, sorted, etc.

If you are filtering be sure to take the date time filter parameters from the client and apply the same rules. Searching in eastern USA time zone for records that fall on the date `2017-02-06` should be translated into records with a date range between `2017-02-06T05:00:00` and `2017-02-07T05:00:00` as that time zone is UTC−05:00 at that point in time.

---

Side Notes

- That there are exceptions to the rule like storing a birth date.
- Personally I prefer storing [DateTime/2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) as UTC over [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql) both in code and in the data store.